# Reinstall removed packages with Smart package manager

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, package-managers

I have a device that is using embedded yocto and smart package manager. I removed `consolekit` package using below command:

```
smart remove consolekit
```

Then I wanted to reinstall, but now smart can't find the package. Is this mean this package is installed manually and it's not part of the repository?

```
smart install consolekit
```

> error: 'consolekit' matches no packages.

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing **package**@ to list all its available arch variants:

```
smart install consolekit@
```

and then select and install the one that matches your arch.